# No Room for Fan Wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

So I replaced a fan today, and the way the bracket is (it's quite large) there wasn't really room to stuff the wires up through the tiny hole at the top of the bracket into the wire box.

I made sure the wire nuts were very snug (and then electrical taped them up as well).

[image]

Is this ok? I've seen other youtube videos of fan installs and i've seen people do similar things with large brackets like this. I made sure to separate the white/green from the red/black as well.

I really hope this is ok, cause this fan was a PITA to install (just time consuming). Everything seems to work fine with it. I made sure the wires are secure, so nothing will be popping out and going below the bracket (not to mention they are too short to go any lower anyways).

(Just for reference, this is a picture before the fan was installed, so there is a cover plate over this that comes with the fan)

Comment: Where's the ceiling rose? Those brackets are to hold something...

Comment: It's sort of hidden, but it's there. the bracket is just very large so theirs no room for wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're fine just so long as the fan enclosure covers the wires and the wires do not interfere with the rotation of the fan.